# How to make 2 lists have different item in C#

Tags: c#, list

Let's say I have 2 Lists which are List Timeslot and List Room. They already have the items in the beginning.

Let's say

```
List Timeslot = T1,T3,T5,T2,T10,T3,T5,T1,T10,T24 

List Room     = R1,R2,R3,R5,R4,R2,R3,R1,R4,R5
```

we can see that in List Timeslot have same item which are in the index of 0 and 7.
but at the index of 0 and 7 in list Room, the items are also same : R1 and R1.

I want to make item in the List Room become different. But we can only change item in list Room.

For example at the index of 0 and 7 in list Room, the items become R1 and R2. 
Let's say I have 20 available rooms : R1 until R20.

Comment: Can't you just increment the R until there is no conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your intent correctly, and you are trying to assign rooms to times, you might try a different structure to accommodate this task. For example, use a `Dictionary<Timeslot, HashSet<Room>()` to hold your data. This would allow you to book any distinct room for any timeslot and achieve what I think your intent to be. However, if you must work with two lists as your have described, then this is not the approach you need.

Here's some untested sample code (I don't know what your structures are):

```
Dictionary<Timeslot, HashSet<Room>> schedule;
List<Room> allRooms;

void AssignRoom(Timeslot time, Room room)
{
    if (!schedule.ContainsKey(time)) 
    {
        // No rooms currently assigned to this time.
        var rooms = new HashSet<Room>() { room };
        schedule.Add(time, rooms);
    }
    else 
    {
        if (schedule[time].Contains(room)) 
        {
            // Room conflict -- add a different room here
            var roomOK = allrooms.Except(schedule[time]).FirstOrDefault();
            if (roomOK == null)
                HeadExplodes();   // You've run out of rooms!
            else
            {
                schedule[time].Add(roomOK); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // No conflicts so just add the room
            schedule[time].Add(room);   
        }
    }
}
```